# TinyMCE insert image not working

Tags: tinymce

There are a few similar questions on SO, but none explain the problem I am having.

I am using [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/) hosted on 1and1.

The problem I am having is with:

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById('content').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="' + url + '" alt="" />');
```

Where `url` could be `http://example.com/uploads/123.jpg`

The image *is* correctly inserted into the tinymce preview area, however the content of the original `textarea` is set to:

```
<img src="%5C" alt="\"\"" />
```

This therefore what is saved to the database.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [PHP Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/magic_quotes).

To solve, place a `php.ini` file in the root of the website containing:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

I found this solution in a post about another software package hosting on 1and1. [How to install Precurio on 1and1 servers](http://www.precurio.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=490)

Answer (score 1):

I am not perfectly sure, what goes wrong here, but i guess it might have to do with the encoding. You may try the configuration settings provided for this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding

Comment: Sorry, the `entity_encoding` hasn't fixed it. Thanks for the answer, I hadn't looked at the encoding.